# Wordpress url redirect better approach

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

. . . . how are you all doing

I have a wordpress blog with 29 posts. The URL structure was

```
http://www.domain.com/category/cat_name/post_name/
```

which I have changed to

```
http://www.domain.com/post_name/
```

using the permalink settings. I also wanted my older links to work so I did redirects using htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /categories/cat_name/post_name/ /post_name/
```

I have checked all links and they are working.

Now what I need to know that is this a good approach or is their a better approach to do it. Doing redirects for 29 links?

Answer (score 0):

Try with de function get_page_by_path($args) of core of wordpress.

See the docs in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path

Get lucky.

Comment: I do not understand how this is relevant